# Password prompt for sudo apps often read-only

Tags: release-juno

When I start apps that require sudo access (gparted, software installations etc) the password prompt often comes up "read-only". I cannot set focus in the textbox and type anything. I have to quit the app and try again, sometimes 2-3 times before I can type in the password.

Any ideas?

[image: Password dialog read-only]

Comment: Do you still have the problem? Please update your status.

Comment: I've switched to use finger print instead of password.